# Three prepositions in a row

Tags: prepositions, writing-style

Does it sound strange or funny to have three prepositions in a row, as in

> He jumped **out from behind** a dustbin?

If yes, is there a simple way to avoid it?

Comment: It sounds ok and it is correct. "Come now young one, if you have something to say to me, then ***come on out from behind*** there and tell me to my face.” https://books.google.it/books?id=GyLeM5uwsKAC&pg=PA1&dq=%22out+from+behind%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAWoVChMIn7P27KzkxwIVwz8aCh11DAIJ#v=onepage&q=%22out%20from%20behind%22&f=false : *Out from behind:* https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+from+behind+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20from%20behind%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 You got the bolding wrong there ;) That should have been "then ***come on out from behind there*** and tell ..."!

Comment: @Josh61 and presumable you could also have had "***come on out from behind there to over here in front of*** me"  too!

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using such a beautiful construct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
He jumped out from behind a dustbin?
```

It's perfectly okay to use this, and most people wouldn't even consider it being weird.

The reason this happens (in this case) is because the verb ends in a preposition, and the location begins with one.

Separated, the sentence becomes

```
He (jumped out) (from) (behind a dustbin)?
```

Which is grammatically similar to

```
He (lives) (in) (France)?
```

The only difference being that the parts used here don't contain prepositions.

You asked how to avoid this repetition of prepositions? Find synonyms that don't have a preposition.

```
He (appeared) (from) (behind a dustbin)?
```

However, I'm having trouble finding a sentence that avoids more than just the first preposition **while still sounding fluent and unforced**.

So you *can* avoid it, but I doubt anyone has the expectation for you to actively avoid it. It's correct the way it is.

Comment: A better answer to the question: "how do I avoid repetition of a preposition?" is "there's no reason to." Three or four prepositions in a row might sound weird in other languages, but it's fine in English.

Comment: @PeterShor Which is basically what I ended my answer with. I replied it's possible, but by no means required or even expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is not unusual. He jumped out|from (his place) behind a dustbin.
A similar sentence

- The cat came out from under the bed.

The British National Corpus has listed 91 examples of "out from behind"
and 122 of "out from under".
http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=out+from+behind&mysubmit=Go